# 'Proof ' that $\ln(x)$ converges

Tags: limits, logarithms, fake-proofs

Where is the flaw in the following 'proof '?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left\{\ln(x)\right\}\right]=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]=0 \implies\lim_{x \to \infty}[\ln(x)]=\text{constant} \in \mathbb{R},$$ therefore $\ln(x)$ converges to some real number. $\square$

Comment: How did you conclude that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\ln(x)$ exists from $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x} = 0$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Surely, if $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left\{\ln(x)\right\}\right]=0,$$ then $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\int 0 \mathrm{d}x\right]=\text{constant}.$$

Comment: This looks like a reverse L'Hospital approach. But working backwards, the 'end' doesn't satisfy the conditions to use L'Hospital.

Comment: @alexqwx: integrating zero?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I'm essentially asking: If the gradient of $\ln(x)$ approaches $0$ as $x \to \infty$, then does it not follow that $\ln(x)$ approaches some constant, as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: @alexqwx, well, no.  In fact you've produced a counterexample to show that the implication "$f'(x) \to 0 \Rightarrow f(x) \to c \in \mathbb R$" is not true in general.  Another counterexample is $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: There's no flaw in what you've done. The thing is, we are usually interested in a derivative at some point, e.g. $f'(x_0)$, where $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Infinity is not a real number though, so derivative doesn't exist, I presume.

Comment: @alexqwx It is not circular. Your "proof" consists of boldly writing "$\implies$", whereas the divergence of $\ln(x)$ or $\sqrt x$ can be easily checked.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Aside from the existence of counter-examples, is there some algebraic reason that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) =0$ does not imply that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ is constant? Or is there an intuitive reason that this is not the case?

Comment: Would you be satisfied with "curves can become as shallow as desired while still tending to infinity"?

Comment: @AntonioVargas No. I think that's the main problem here. I understand your counterexamples, but this doesn't make sense intuitively.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the main problem is, then.

Comment: Derivatives are local behavior. Local behavior for long periods affect global behavior.

Comment: @AntonioVargas The problem is, geometrically, if $y$ eventually doesn't change with $x$ (i.e. the gradient tends to zero) then surely $y$ tends to some constant.

Comment: @alexqwx, there's a difference between the gradient being *eventually zero* and the gradient *tending to zero while still remaining nonzero*.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes! I've edited my penultimate comment.

Comment: @alexqwx: Perhaps it helps to note that your purported argument is equivalent to the common misperception that an infinite series necessarily converges if its terms decrease to zero.

Comment: That's the crux of it though.  The slope can tend to zero, but if it tends to zero slowly enough then the curve doesn't 'flatten out' enough to stop it from going to infinity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not even clear what it means to say that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ "is a constant," since it isn't a function of any variable, it's just a limit, if the limit exists.

But consider $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. We know that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{d}{dx}f(x) = 0$, but is $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x}$ a constant?

One thing we can say, if $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{d}{dx}f(x) = 0$, is that if $D$ is any constant, then $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(f(x+D)-f(x)\right)=0$$

This claim is just nonsense:

> If $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left\{\ln(x)\right\}\right]=0$$
>   then $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\int 0\mathrm{d}x\right]=\text{constant}$$

The fundamental theorem of calculus does not even remotely support that. We have:

$$\ln(x)=\int_{1}^x \frac{1}{t}dt$$

Note, there is no $x$ in that expression except on the limits. So:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln(x)=\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{t}dt$$

The indefinite integral:

This expression:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int \frac{1}{x}dx$$

Doesn't actually make sense, because $\int\frac{1}{x}dx$ is not well-defined, and, while it is common to refer it as a function of $x$, $x$ is not a free variable.

A simple example, with no infinities: $$\lim_{x\to 1}\int x\,dx = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$ But:

$$\int \left(\lim_{x\to 1}x\right)\,dx=\int dx=x$$

You simply can't swap integrals and limits that way.

Comment: So is the error in thinking that $$\lim_{x \to \infty } f(x) \equiv f\left(\lim_{x \to \infty }[x]\right)$$?

Comment: @alexqwx $f$ isn't even defined at $\infty$. What would that mean? What is $\lim_{x\to\infty} x$?

Comment: Ah! Got it! Thanks.  Am I right in thinking the error is in claiming that the derivative of a limit is the limit of the derivative (and similarly, that the limit of the integral is the integral of the limit)?

Comment: No, you are getting major conceptual things wrong, not just that part. (Quite often, the limit of the derivative is the derivative of the limit - when the function is defined at the limit value - Here $x=\infty$, $f(\infty)$ is not defined - and when the derivative is continuous at that value. The key problem is your understanding of the fundamental theorem of calculus, and the meaning of $x$ in $\int f(x)dx$.

Comment: What part of FTC am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The part where you use indefinite integrals @alexqwx

Comment: Specifically, $\int f(x)dx = \int f(t)dt$. They mean the same thing - indefinite integrals define a set of functions, and the variable inside the integral is irrelevant. What is $\lim_{x\to \infty} \int f(t)dt$? Why is it different than $\lim_{x\to\infty} \int f(x)dx$? It shouldn't be, but your trick indicates there is a difference. That's because you aren't understanding what the indefinite integral *is*.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are saying that if
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0\implies\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\text{ converges}
$$
in your instance, $f(x)=\frac1x$.

Although this would make analysis of integrals much simpler, it is not true. There are many functions that vanish at infinity whose integral diverges ($\frac1x$ being a good example).

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$\int\lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx = \frac xa + C \neq \lim_{x \to a}\int \frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm dx = \log(a) + C$$

It should be clear that in general this procedure produces functions of $x$ on the left and constants on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Notice though the derivative of ln(x) converges to $0$ that for any interval $[a,b]$ (for $a,b\in\mathbb{R})$ that the derivate is positive every where, thus though yes the derivative does go to $0$ as you approach infinity. At no point is it actually $0$ any interval of $[0,\infty)$ thus you can't employ the property that if if a function has derivative $0$ everywhere within some interval then it is constant on that interval.

Note also if what you said is true that would imply there would be for some a such $[a,\infty)$ that $e^{x}$ wouldn't be a valid function (since it would just a vertical line at that point)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically what about your proof is wrong aside from the non sequitur.

if I wanted to prove the opposite I might look at a higher base that also happens to be an integer, which will be easier to think about... so if

There exists no limit to log10(x) as x approaches infinity, then no limit exists for ln(x) as x approaches infinity.

This is easier for me to mentally prove for a very large x there exists a number n that is the number I need to satisfy 10^n = x