# Why doesn't $\ln (x)$ have a horizontal asymptote even though its derivative is $1/x$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

My understanding is that the derivative gives the gradient of the function at that point.

So for the function $x^2$, its gradient at point $x=10$ is equal to $20$.

Extrapolating this to $\ln (x)$, I encounter a problem. 
Since $\frac{d}{dx}\ln (x) = 1/x$, the gradient of $\ln (x)$ at $x=100$ is given by $0.01$. What about as $x \to \infty$? Shouldn't the gradient of $\ln(x)$ tend to $0$?

And if so, why doesn't $\ln(x)$ have a horizontal asymptote?

Comment: $\;\log x\;$ does have a vertical asymptote at $\;x=0\;$ . Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Timbuc sorry I should have specified horizontal asymptote

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909069/proof-that-lnx-converges

Comment: $\ln (2^x) = x*ln(2)$, so no horizontal asymptote.

Answer (score 13):

To help your intuitions: $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ has no asymptote at $+\infty$, although $f'(x)$ tends to 0.

Answer (score 11):

Let's revisit the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Horizontal_asymptotes).

> We say $y=f(x)$ has a *horizontal asymptote at $y=L$* if either $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L\quad\text{ or }\quad\displaystyle\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=L.$$

Since $\ln x$ is only defined for $x>0$, we need only consider
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln x=\infty
$$
so $y=\ln x$ does *not* have any horizontal asymptote (just as $y=\sqrt{x}$ does not).

---

PS Also to correct something from the comments: the definition of a horizontal asymptote is **not** "a horizontal line that the graph of the function gets closer and closer to, but does not touch". See, for example, $y=e^{-x}\sin x$ which has a horizontal asymptote at $y=0$ even though it intersects $y=0$ infinitely many times. This is a very common error that is propagated by teachers for some reason!

Be guided by definitions rather than well-intentioned but often sloppy heuristics. ;-)

Comment: I was a victim of the mentioned horizontal asymptote fallacy. Afterward an awkward first calculus exam where I relied on my highschool asymptote-finding skills, I started reading the textbooks.

Comment: Thanks for that! It just occurred to me that I have never seen "horizontal asymptote" defined in any analysis text.

Comment: +1 for the definition of a horizontal asymptote is not "a horizontal line that the graph of the function gets closer and closer to, but does not touch" ... I have found it very hard to persuade people otherwise, once someone has told them this is what an asymptote is then the idea seems to stick, unfortunately!

Comment: "an asymptote is a horizontal line that the graph of the function gets closer and closer to, but does not touch" - @JohnD why do you think this is not a true statement?

Comment: @Jim The last paragraph in the post explains why.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the gradient of $\ln x$ "at infinity" (more precisely, in the limit as $x$ becomes increasingly large) is zero.

What this means is that the larger $x$ is, the less of an increase in $\ln x$ you get by a small change to $x$. It doesn't mean there has to be a horizontal asymptote ("adding up infinitely many infinitesimal things doesn't necessarily give you something finite"). Consider for instance the discrete analogue of $\ln x$, the harmonic series:
$$g(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}$$

$g(n)$ diverges for $n\to \infty$, even though each term contributes less and less to the total sum as $i$ gets larger.

EDIT:

Yes, but the gradient going to zero is *not* sufficient to guarantee that the function approaches some horizontal line. Take a look again at the harmonic series: as $i$ increases the change if $g$ from the $\frac{1}{i}$ term becomes smaller and smaller, but $g(n)$ does not approach any line.

Comment: I dont understand why there isn't a horizontal asymptote. Isn't a horizontal asymptote defined by the line where a function is getting closer to but doesnt touch?

Comment: Lets say a function has a horizontal asymptote of line y=m. This implies that as x gets very large, the function gets flatter and closer to the line y=m. Doesnt this also imply that the gradient tends to 0?

Comment: Yes. The implication only goes one way, though: *if* the function has a horizontal asymptote, then the limit of the gradient (if it is defined) as $x\to \infty$ is zero. The converse is not true.

Comment: I see what you are saying but I dont see why. If the gradient is approaching zero, doesnt it follow that the function is approaching a line?

Comment: @user_of_math Certainly; a monotonic surjective function can't have horizontal asymptotes.

Comment: @surelyourejoking The suggestion to look at $\sqrt{x}$ is also a good one. That's another example of a function whose gradient gets smaller and smaller, but does *not* approach a line. I don't know what else to tell you; you'll have to look at examples like $\sqrt{x}$ and the harmonic series yourself, and convince yourself that the intuition that if a function's rate of growth is always decreasing, it must have an upper limit, is wrong.\

Comment: I suppose so...

Answer (score 0):

A straight line is an asymptote of a curve y=f(x), if the perpendicular distance of a point on the curve to the straight line tends to zero as the point goes towards +/- infinity along the curve.  This definition makes it very precise

Padmanabhan